# Wordpress: Show grand children categories - not just children categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category) {
    $parent_category_ID = 40;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0, // Set to 0 to show empty categories and 1 to hide them
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
    echo '<ul class="woo_subcategory_list">';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        $link = get_term_link( $subcategory->slug, $subcategory->taxonomy );
        echo '<li><a href="'. $link .'">'.$subcategory->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This works well, except it only show the children - not the grandchildren. ie

- Child 1
- Grandchild 2
- Grandchild 3
- Child 2
- Child 3

Only shows Child 1, Child 2, Child 3.

How can I modify this code, so that it shows the grand children as well (in existing hierarchy)

Comment: you need a recursive loop for the children of children of the children and their children's children

Answer (score -1):

To display both children and grandchildren categories in WordPress, you can modify the code by implementing a recursive function to iterate through the category hierarchy.

**Here's an updated version of your code:**

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($category) {
    $parent_category_ID = 40;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'category'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);

    echo '<ul class="woo_subcategory_list">';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        get_category_hierarchy($subcategory);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function get_category_hierarchy($category, $level = 0) {
    $link = get_term_link($category->slug, $category->taxonomy);
    echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $category->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'category'
    );

    $children = get_categories($args);

    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            get_category_hierarchy($child, $level + 1);
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID(40);
```

This should output a nested list structure with both children and grandchildren. Adjust the parameters as needed to fit your specific requirements.